# Где хранятся сессии php Apache под Windows?

Tags: apache, php

Подскажите, где хранятся сессии PHP Apache под Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вызвать [session_save_path()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-save-path.php) и узнать)